# Pass arguments from one variadic function to another

Tags: racket

Say I have a function which opens chrome and gives any number of args (urls)

```
(define (chrome . args)
  (subprocess #f #f #f "/usr/bin/google-chrome" (car args)))
```

Above I'm only taking one argument. I actually want all arguments applied.

Args gets created as a list but subprocess requires its arguments to come one at a time after the process name. How do I expand the args list into the subprocess function.

Comment: check on `apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply`

```html
#lang racket/base

(define (chrome . args)
  (apply subprocess #f #f #f "/usr/bin/google-chrome-beta" args))

(chrome "https://racket-lang.org" "https://stackoverflow.com")
```